# Android: Context object

Tags: android, android-context

When programming on Android, we use context object everywhere (maybe `context` keyword or `this` keyword), but I don't really understand what its purpose.

For example, when we add `UI Component` such as `TextView`:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);  //this simple line make me headache
setContentView(textView);
```

The first time I think above line is : `this` keyword mean: this textView will be assign to current screen. But after that, I see that is a wrong thinking because line `setContentView(textView)` do what I think.

So, who can explain for me, what purpose when we declare `context object` in above example. (and others case, if you please, tell me more :D)

thanks :)

Comment: Good question.By the same way I thought it like these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need the `Context` class is when creating a view dynamically in an activity. For example, you may want to dynamically create a `TextView` from code. To do so, you instantiate the `TextView` class. The constructor for the `TextView` class takes a `Context` object, and because the `Activity` class is a subclass of `Context`, you can use the `this` keyword to represent the `Context` object.

Comment: It is well explained why we need context while dynamically creating a text view. But while dynamically creating arrays of text views we don't have to mention any context. Why is that so ? TextView[] textview = new TextView[10];

Answer (score 7):

A `Context` object provides access to the application's resources and other features. Each `Activity` is a `Context` and each `View` needs a `Context` so it can retrieve whatever resources it needs (including things like system-defined resources).

The second line tells the `Activity` object to use that particular `View` (a `TextView`) as the top-level user interface element to display for that `Activity`. There is no conflict between that and using the `Activity` as a `Context` for constructing the `TextView` in the first place. They are different things.

Comment: Sorry, can I has a question: as you say, `View` need a `Context` to use resource (system resource, example). So, why they don't do automatically ?

Comment: @hqt - The `Context` object is created by the framework and passed to your `Activity` after it is constructed but before the `onCreate()` method is called. (This is done by calling the `attachBaseContext()` method inherited from its parent class, `ContextThemeWrapper`.) Since the framework (normally) controls the creation of `Activity` objects, it can make this call automatically. The same does not hold for `View` objects, because their creation is under your control. (Note that it is handled more or less automatically by `View` objects inflated from XML.)

Answer (score 3):

Why does it need a context? [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context%29) says that every view needs the context to access the right resources (e.g. the theme, strings etc.).

But why in the constructor and not through [setContentView(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29)?

1. Because the resources must be accessible while the view is being constructed (the constructor will need some resources to fully initialise the view).
2. This allows the flexibility of using a context that is different from the one of the current activity (imagine a view that uses some other string resources and not the ones from the current activity).
3. The designers of the Android SDK seem to have chosen that the context must be set only once and then stay the same throughout the lifetime of the view.

Why isn't the context determined automatically at construction point?

1. Because there exists no static variable that would tell you the current global context of your application. The method [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) is the closest to this, but it's not static, so you need an instance of the `Activity` object to call it.
2. The Java language provides an option to look through the call stack and find whether the `View` has been constructed in a `Context` class. But what if there are many? Or what if there are none? This method is very expensive and error prone. So the designers of the API decided that a context *must* be manually provided.

Comment: Same question as I have asked Ted Hopp, Can you tell me why android don't design that they do automatically, please ? Thanks :)